# Already installed Html test runner but it shows error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HtmlTestRunner' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

using pip I installed new version of HtmlTestRunner in python 3.6, but while I run python file through command prompt its throws error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "seleniumUnitTest.py", line 3, in 
>       import HtmlTestRunner
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HtmlTestRunner'

Comment: The issue has been fixed by shutting down the pc and boot up again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `python program.py` instead of `python3 program.py` fixed my problem in Windows 10.